# Using CCS for reading position & speed of motor using encoder. Please explain the following syntax

Tags: c, pointers, syntax, encoder

Please explain the following syntax in C language.

***Syntax*** -  variable_name &= 0xFFF(Hex value);

The code is give below

```
// The following lines calculate
//
// p->thetaMech ~= QPOSCNT / mechScaler [current cnt/(total cnt in 1 rev)]
//
// where mechScaler = 4000 cnts/revolution
//
temp = (int32_t)p->thetaRaw * (int32_t)p->mechScaler;   // Q0 * Q26 = Q26
temp &= 0x03FFF000;

p->thetaMech = (int16_t)(temp >> 11);                    // Q26 -> Q15
p->thetaMech &= 0x7FFF;
```

Comment: The `op=` operators in C use the left hand side as both the assignment target and the first operand of the corresponding operation.  For example, `a += 2;` is equivalent to `a = a + 2;`.  In your case, `a &= b;` is equivalent to `a = a & b;`

Answer (score 0):

@TomKarzes is totally correct. As additional information. The `&` is the bitwise `AND` operator. Simply spoken, adding 2 values in `binary form`, each position where both have bit 1 remain 1, in all other cases it becomes 0. Example:

```
Bitwise AND &

  11001000 // decimal: 200  hexadecimal: 0xC8
& 10111000 // decimal: 184  hexadecimal: 0xB8
  -------- 
= 10001000 // result decimal: 136 hexadecimal: 0x88
```